# limit of the complex sequences

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

How can we find $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{in}}{2^n+in!}\right)$?

Can we use the fact $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(z_n\right)=z_0\leftrightarrow \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\left|z_n-z_0\right|\right)=0$ ?

Comment: The expression you want to find a limit of is not well-defined.  At best it is a multi-valued expression.  While some reasoning can be done with such cases, you need to present the context in which it is supposed to make sense (and then we can advise you).

Answer (score 1):

**First one question**: how do you define $\sqrt[n]{in}$?

**Providing you answer this question**, you'll be able to prove that:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \vert \sqrt[n]{in} \vert = 1 \text{ and } \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \vert 2^n+in! \vert = +\infty$$ hence your limit exists and is equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{\sqrt[n]{in}}{2^n+in!}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{\left(in\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{2^n+in!}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\exp\left(\ln\left(\frac{\left(in\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{2^n+in!}\right)\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\exp\left(\frac{\ln(in)}{n}-\ln(2^n+in!)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{\ln(in)}{n}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\ln(2^n+in!)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}n}\left(\ln(in)\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}n}\left(n\right)}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\ln(2^n+in!)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\ln(2^n+in!)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\frac{1}{n}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\ln(2^n+in!)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(0-\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\ln(2^n+in!)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(-\lim_{n\to\infty}\space\ln(2^n+in!)\right)$$